# Causes of "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(Z)V"

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-bahir

I am trying to run spark structured streaming MQTT using Apache Bahir by modifying the sample wordcount example provided.

SPARK version: spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.

I am using this command to run the program: `bin\spark-submit --packages org.apache.bahir:spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11:2.2.0 mqtt.py`

Below is my code:

```
# mqtt.py

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount")\
        .getOrCreate()
    broker_uri = 'xyz.com:1883'
    lines = (spark\
        .readStream\
        .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")\
        .option("topic","xyz")\
        .load("tcp://{}".format(broker_uri)))\

    # Split the lines into words
    words = lines.select(
        # explode turns each item in an array into a separate row
        explode(
            split(lines.value, ' ')
        ).alias('word')
    )

    # Generate running word count
    wordCounts = words.groupBy('word').count()

    # Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
    query = wordCounts\
        .writeStream\
        .outputMode('complete')\
        .format('console')\
        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
```

But I get the following error on getting query:

```
17/11/09 19:48:14 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
17/11/09 19:48:16 INFO StreamExecution: Starting [id = e0335f31-f3e0-4ee1-a774-52582268845c, runId = f6a87268-164c-4eab-82db-1ac0bacd2bad]. Use C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\temporary-42cbc22f-7c1d-413c-b81c-3d4496f8e297 to store the query checkpoint.
17/11/09 19:48:16 WARN MQTTStreamSourceProvider: If `clientId` is not set, a random value is picked up.
Recovering from failure is not supported in such a case.
17/11/09 19:48:16 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = e0335f31-f3e0-4ee1-a774-52582268845c, runId = f6a87268-164c-4eab-82db-1ac0bacd2bad] terminated with error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(Z)V
        at org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider.createSource(MQTTStreamSource.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:155)
        at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:194)
        at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(StreamExecution.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan(StreamExecution.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:276)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = e0335f31-f3e0-4ee1-a774-52582268845c, runId = f6a87268-164c-4eab-82db-1ac0bacd2bad]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(Z)V
        at org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider.createSource(MQTTStreamSource.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:155)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Fall-17/Transportation/spark/mqtt.py", line 84, in <module>

    query.awaitTermination()
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\streaming.py", line 106, in awaitTermination
        at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:194)  File "C:\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 75, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: u'org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(Z)V\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: [id = e0335f31-f3e0-4ee1-a774-52582268845c, runId = f6a87268-164c-4eab-82db-1ac0bacd2bad]\nCurrent Committed Offsets: {}\nCurrent Available Offsets: {}\n\nCurrent State: INITIALIZING\nThread State: RUNNABLE'

        at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(StreamExecution.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan(StreamExecution.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:276)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
17/11/09 19:48:16 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it.  Your condition might be different from mine.  I know I should just comment instead of answer.  However my reputation is too low to comment.

In my condition, my maven project included dependencies of both org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11:2.2.0 and org.apache.bahir:spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11:2.2.0

spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11 depends on org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3: 1.0.2

spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11 depends on org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3: 1.1.0

1.1.0 has MqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect, but 1.0.2 doesn't.

I removed the spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11 dependency then it works.